# Parsing more than one page from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetching eventbrite's API formatted as JSON,  the issue is JSON can only have 50 Items, which means the Json does not have all the information.
so here 
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?token=XXX&location.address=Lodnon&page=1&expand=venue

this is API, as you can see this is only page=1,  it has 31pages - so I need page =1 =2 =3 =4 ....=31

SO I tired to parse all the pages of data, but it was not going well

Please check my code out

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
gather(){
let requests = [];
for (let i=1; i<32; i++) {
requests.push(fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?
location.address=glasgow&page='+i+'&token=XXX&expand=venue').then(r => 
r.json()));
}
Promise.all(requests).then((responses) => {
   let arr = [];
for (let response of responses) {
for (let event of response.events) {
    //console.log(event)
}
```

}
                                                                                                })   .catch((error) => { console.error(error);

```
  });
}

 componentWillMount(){

  this.gather()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to match the pagination and not get all the pages at once, but if you really need to do it, I don't think it's a good idea to `setState` so many times -- ideally you would make all the requests and `setState` once at the end. Something like this:

Batch up all the requests into an array of promises:

```
let requests = [];
for (let i=0; i<32; i++) {
  requests.push(fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=glasgow&page='+i+'&token=XXX&expand=venue').then(r => r.json()));
}
```

Run all the requests at once and wait for them all to finish, then do the setState once all the requests have finished:

```
Promise.all(requests).then((responses) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let response of responses) {
    for (let event of response.events) {
      // extract the event info and add it to the individual arrays/items
      // ...
```

Also, not sure how your app is structured to use this data, but it might be easier to just keep it in one object instead of having separate arrays for each:

```
{
  name,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  url
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answering me I have got undefined is not an object(evaluating '_iterator2[tydeofsymbol=="function"?].,,

Comment: when I print out  response it retrieves bunch of [object , object]  , and when I print out  response.events , it said undeifned

Comment: @user9375305 that new code you have seems to be working for me, when I do `console.log(event.url);` I get a bunch of results with the urls from the api. Also remember to put your access token back to the url, I replaced it with `XXX` to keep it private.

Comment: oh yea sorry my bad, I did not notice XXX... Thanks a lot !

Comment: would you mind to write a code using pagination ? I think I need pagination... still unsure of implementation ...