# React - api calls from more than one page using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from more than one page. However, the URL doesn't have a `&page=...` such as this example [Parsing more than one page from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142134/parsing-more-than-one-page-from-api)

This is the API I am struggling with: https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debate&tag=politics/politics&from-date=2014-01-01&api-key=test and as it says its currentPage: 1, pages: 1711 so it clearly has more has 1 page.

This is my code so far

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=b0e6548b-b042-46c6-821e-94aa7b68exxx"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          articles: res.data.response.results.slice(0, 15),
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Paginate with React itself, See how `antd` paginates or use it

Comment: right ... I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Check the API because I able to change the page using page filter to the URL. https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debate&tag=politics/politics&from-date=2014-01-01&api-key=test&page=5. But not able get the page size though.

Comment: That's perfect, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1